# eMedNy Soap Interop: Eligibility Fault

Tags: web-services, soap, x12, hipaa

I've been working on setting up a Soap Client to consume eMedNy's services as per their [instructions](https://www.emedny.org/selfhelp/SOAP/eMedNY_Meds_History_Service_User_Guide_1.1.pdf).

This is what I'm currently doing:

```
string _270Msg = "..."; // 270 Message 

// convert string to array of bytes
byte [] bytes = new byte[_270Msg.Length * sizeof(char)]; 
System.Buffer.BlockCopy( _270Msg.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length );

// Wrap bytes in eMedNy-supplied Transaction Type
Transaction t = new Transaction();
t.transData = bytes;

client.getEligibility( t );
```

I believe my messages have succeeded in making it through their security gate, but I've now been getting the following error message back from their server:

```
An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See
inner FaultException for the fault code and detail. ---> 
System.ServiceModeultException: Eligibility
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Does anyone have experience with this who can direct me on how to fix this?

Comment: I'm willing to bet this might be an authentication issue.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11517772/wcf-unsecured-or-incorrectly-secured-fault-was-received-from-the-other-party

Comment: Actually, at that point the issue was the format of the `270`. After that was fixed, there was/is a slew of other issues which I'm still working on.